# C# Prevent my .exe win application on being renamed?

Tags: c#, exe, file-rename

Hi is it possible to prevent my .exe application on being renamed..?

here is the senario(my problem)

After i Run my program, (lets say i run MyApp.exe)
a unfriendly user suddenly for fun, renamed my MyApp.exe to ... lets say Goodtime.exe

after that. he log-off windows(xp) and then when my program is attempting to run on startup
MyApp.exe , i wont because it got renamed

is it possible to prevent this through codes?

thanks to anyone who would help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible.

However there is an alternative to do that.
You can set the user to have limited rights on his user account to the computer. In that case he cannot rename files in such a way he wanted. This is a restriction provided by the operating system in which only the administrators of the computer can set these restrictions to user accounts.

**EDIT**
What I mean here is if you are the administrator of the computer, as an alternative you can manually limit the privileges of the users who logs-in to the computer. For a better understanding on what I mean, please read the replies on my post. :)

Comment: could you elaborate on your second paragraph? Are you proposing changes to the privileges granted to a user account? And how would you suggest doing this?

Comment: I'm assuming that if the Katherina is the administrator of the computer she can limit the privileges of the users who logs in to the computer. But, in your scenario if the user owns the computer then, there's nothing we can do about it. They can rename the files anytime they wanted.

Comment: just so long as nobody thinks it's a good idea for a program's install package to start modifying user privileges!

Comment: Yeah absolutely not a good idea to modify user privileges from the install package and also that's not what I suppose to mean. What I mean is that she can manually set limitations to the users who logs-in to the computer. Sorry to confuse you with my answer, I will try to edit it to make it more understandable :)

Comment: that's OK. I wasn't confused. I was though imagining that OP might have got the wrong idea.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean on that. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't really attempt to stop this. It's the user's computer and if they want to rename files on their computer they can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your application somewhere the user is less likely to go and rename it, like in the program files folder. But you can't stop them actually renaming the application.

Answer (score 0):

If the user isn't an administrator on that machine they won't have permissions to rename files in the Program Files directory by default.  One would hope that unfriendly users aren't administrators on the target machine (If they are, they can do a lot worse than renaming one application file).

Answer (score 0):

You can check what name the executable has when it's being run.

But you cannot prevent a user from renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using clickonce publishing. For the life of me I can never guarantee I can find the ruddy application after installing it with clickonce so that might stop your friendly user messing with the app? ;-)

Here is some info on [ClickOnce Publishing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

In essence, write an application, right click the project/solution, choose "Publish", then follow the wizard.

It won't guarantee the user won't be able to rename and mess with the files, but it'll make it harder.

Answer (score 0):

1. By permissions way as most folks here explained.
2. Stupid and waste method is to have a daemon (Service) running accessing this file all time since system boot. That way system wont allow this executable to be renamed unless this daemon is stopped.

Answer (score -3):

you can prevent renaming or moving your exe file while it is running.
Open the exe file within your exe file for reading and deny writing.
Keep this file open as long as it runs.

Comment: This does not address the issue the OP has.